# Which operations are simplified by storing the 'parent' of each node in a red-black tree?

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, red-black-tree

Some red-black tree implementations store a parent for each node.

Which common operations *(insert, remove, pop_min, pop_max, iteration... etc)* can be simplified using this extra information?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347018/red-black-tree-how-to-find-the-nodes-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a parent helps with any operation that may need to step up the tree, these include both iteration and removal (including pop min/max).

Finding the next ancestor (which may be a grandparent or further) would appear to be an O(log n) operation with or without a parent pointer but they are not the same, given that most nodes are at the bottom of the tree having a parent means that only one step up is required in a typical case (and that step is already known) whereas without a parent you have to step down most of the tree in most cases. Basically having a parent pointer inverts the ancestor search problem.

From an implementation side (rather than algorithm) I also find that insert is easier with a parent - I prefer implementing the rebalance for both insert and remove as an iterative loop rather than recursive tail call.